# A general derivation for a combinatoric problem

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any derivation for the problems:

> $1.$Dividing $n$ identical things into $r$ identical groups where some
>   groups may be empty or all $n$ things can go to any one group.
>
> $2.$Dividing $n$ identical items into $r$ identical groups where there
>   is at-least one item in every group.

I am not sure if this is modeled as some other known problem,what I am looking for, is a nice approach/derivation for solving these kind of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are refering to  [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29).

Edited: The restriction of "r groups" introduce a restriction. The second problem would correspond to counting $p(n,r)$, number of partitions of a number $n$ in $r$ parts. This is not trivial (see [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf) or [here](http://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf), our counting corresponds to $p(n,k)$ there).
The first problem would correspond to the number of partions of size up to $r$, hence it can be expressed as a sum $\sum_{k=1}^r p(n,k)$

Comment: May be related but I think not exactly as there is a restriction of $r$ which needs to be considered explicitly?!

Comment: YOu are right, added info.

Comment: I agree that this is not trivial,thanks for the infos. :-)